# Give tag to Pan Gesture for all UIScrollView's Subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

In my Application, I have a `UIScrollView` in which I'm putting `UIButton`s dynamically. I gave tags to all the button's in `UIScrollView`. **I need Pan Gesture on each button in UIScrollView**. But the problem is that **only the last button is getting Pan Gesture** and **not all** the buttons.

My Code:

```
for (int i =0; i<[arrayForTitles count]; i++)
{       
    view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:0.85]];
    view.tag=i;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, varForTitleViewHeight, scrView.frame.size.width, 50);
    [scrView addSubview:view];

    //************** view when pan gesture done  ********************

    viewForPanGesture = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [viewForPanGesture setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    viewForPanGesture.tag=i;
    viewForPanGesture.frame = CGRectMake(100, varForTitleViewHeight, 151, view.frame.size.height);
    [scrView addSubview:viewForPanGesture];

    btnOnScrollTitle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnOnScrollTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0,varForTitleViewHeight,scrView.frame.size.width, 50);
    [btnOnScrollTitle setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    btnOnScrollTitle.tag = i;
    [btnOnScrollTitle addTarget:self action:@selector(blackViewMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scrView addSubview:btnOnScrollTitle];

    panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [btnOnScrollTitle addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    varForTitleViewHeight = varForTitleViewHeight+51;
}
```

Now, how to give each object of the `UIScrollView` the Pan Gesture, and not only the last object.

Any idea, code, tutorial, or link will be great help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no error in code and don't need any modification.you just access them with wrong way.
here the code for it.

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
 {
   if ((UIButton *)[sender.view viewWithTag:0])   //where  no. '0' tag of button.;
      {
         // code it
      }
   if ((UIButton *)[sender.view viewWithTag:1])   
      {
         // code it
      }


 }
```

Comment: ya but bro this is for static view's. I have dynamic view's in UIScrollView. it may be contain 100 View or may be 1000. so need to differentiate all the Pan gesture for all the view.

Comment: you can use any loop funcion for it if it's similar.

Comment: i am just sliding another small view when pan gesture occur like in table view's default edit cell functionality. and your answer is not working for dynamic views.

Comment: Your code didn't work perfectly.... for dynamic view's i used if ((UIButton *)[sender.view viewWithTag:sender.view.tag]){} it will give me the exact tag of the view's gesture. and after that some logical finishing required. I accept your answer as you gave me some hint of it. happy coding....